# Python cleaning up / refactoring redundant code

Tags: python, refactoring

This is probably quite a newbie question. I started learning python by programming webscrapers. In each module I have a default set of imports and profile sets that I need for it. They are always the same, initializing the selenium webdrivers, setting it into headless mode, etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
import openpyxl
...
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
...
```

They take up a lot of lines in each file and I wanted to clean this up a bit by having them all in a seperate .py module but I don't understand how I can accomplish that. Simply putting all that into a function and importing that .py file doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're halfway there - put all the imports into a separate .py file in the same directory, let's call it `selenium_imports.py`. To get all the modules into your namespaces, you'll have to run the following:

```py
from selenium_imports import *
```

Then all your modules will be loaded correctly.